# Using init-methods to avoid allocating object using new - is this bad design?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization, new-operator

I have recently started using init methods instead of passing parameters to the constructor when designing classes in C++:

```
Class A {
public:
A();
init(int number);
...
};
```

Instead of:

```
Class A {
public:
A(int number);
};
```

This allows me to use A as a member in other classes like this:

```
class B {
A m_a;
};
```

Instead of the way I used to do it:

```
class B {
A *m_a;
};
```

(and then allocate m_a in B's constructor.)

The good thing about using init functions is that I don't have to worry about deleting m_a since it will be destroyed when the instance of B is destroyed.

My question is: Is there any downside to using init-methods that I should know about? Will this overflow the stack etc?

Everything is working fine so far, but I thought that I should ask before I write to much code in this way.

Comment: I don't follow. Why do you think a class with a constructor can't be a member of another class? You just need the outer class to initialise it in its constructors. There's no need for pointers or weird two-stage initialisation shenanigans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not obliged to use pointers to have class instances as attributes.

```
Class B {
public:
    explicit B(int i); // notice the explicit, btw
    A m_a;
};

B::B(int i)
    : m_a(i) { // will call the constructor of "A" with "i" as argument
}
```

`m_a` will be destroyed when the instance of `B` is destroyed too.

By adding an `init` method, you're defeating the purpose of constructors: you can have an object that's not fully built. Instead of forgetting to delete `m_a`, you take the risk to forget to init it.

Comment: Note, you're invoking A's **copy constructor** here.

Comment: Good spot! I changed it to a simple constructor for clarity :)

Comment: Oh, this is actually the right way of doing it. I'm glad that I didn't write too many classes using init methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's a horrible pattern.

The object will be in an undefined state between its construction and your calling init. Also you have to think about making init thread safe, along with making init robust if called more than once.

Also note that you can call a constructor from another one from c++11 onwards. So the argument that an init function eliminates duplication of code that could arise from having multiple constructors no longer applies.

Comment: The need to handle the case when init is called multiple times is a very good point. Could you explain more about why constructors are better for thread safety?

Answer (score 0):

You can store properties by value even if you need non-default constructor to instantiate them. In the constructor of class `B` you'll need to explicitly instantiate the `m_a` via intialization list, e.g. `B(int number):m_a(number){}`. Using initialization functions to overcome this "problem" is really unnecessary here as the language supports this natively.